# Salutations pour plusieurs emails dans la même matinée

Tags: salutations, style-de-rédaction, travail, registre-soutenu, email

Au début d'un email professionel (à 9h) à un client à qui j'écris pour la première fois, je salue par « Bonjour Robert ».
Mais quelle salutation utiliser dans les emails suivants (à 9h30, 10h, ...) ?

Exemple:

> Bonjour Robert,
> Merci d'avoir renseigné votre adresse email sur notre site web, blabla
>
> Bonjour Nicolas,
> Avez-vous des produits blabla
>
> **Rebonjour** Robert,
> Tout à fait, nous disposons de blabla

Que dire à la place de **rebonjour** ?

- Vaut-il mieux ne plus saluer ? Y a-t-il un risque d'être perçu comme malpoli ?
- Il y a bien « Pour faire suite à la conversation précédente, ... » mais ça paraît lourd, surtout à partir du troisième envoi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je dirais que cela dépend de l'interlocuteur et surtout du degré de familiarité que vous possédez avec lui.

Il y a plusieurs alternatives :

> Re,

C'est informel, mais de plus en plus utilisé dans les milieux professionnels lorsque les relations avec la personne sont plus détendues.

Le passe partout :

> Robert,

ou

> Monsieur XXX,

C'est tout à fait correct, je le recommande dans les cas où l'on peut se permettre d'appeler la personne par son prénom.

Comment: degré de familiarité: professionnel, contacté pour la première fois, donc relativement formel. Domaine de l'informatique, donc pas excessivement formel non plus.

Comment: Dans ce cas, comme vous l'avez contacté en utilisant son prénom, j'opterais pour la formule "Robert," pour la suite de chaque échange après le premier "Bonjour Robert," de la journée.

Answer (score 2):

Il est tout à fait correct de mettre *Bonjour Robert*, cela met une distance respectueuse avec la personne à qui l'on écrit.

S'il s'agit d'un familier, tout est possible, mais il n'est pas adroit  d'être trop familier ou trop humoriste, la personne qui va recevoir le message n'est pas obligatoirement en état de goûter cet humour.

Il est toujours gagnant d'utiliser un style correct, voire un style élégant.

S'il y a plusieurs destinataires un seul *Bonjour* peut suffire,

Dans le cas de Robert, *sur une réponse dans le même courriel*, il n'est pas nécessaire de mettre le nom de l'interlocuteur.

S'il s'agit d'un sujet différent, on peut écrire :

> Robert, 
> Je te re-contacte aujourd'hui au sujet de ...

Comment: degré de familiarité: professionnel, contacté pour la première fois, donc relativement formel, vouvoiement en tous cas. Domaine de l'informatique, donc pas excessivement formel non plus.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul La relecture d'un échange de courriels dans un service informatique par un consultant externe pour régler un problème épineux m'a définitivement éclairé : la familiarité au-delà du tutoiement est dangereuse en cas de tensions. Le directeur d'un très gros projet, énarque de surcroît, à le tutoiement facile, mais instinctivement catalogue la compétence des intervenants sur la qualité de leurs écrits. En entreprise, tous les courriels sensibles sont conservés, et une relecture, ne serait-ce que six mois après ...